# Different heights with the same padding

Tags: html, css, button, label

I have the following padding: `padding:12px 24px;` for input button and label for checkbox.
Font is set in body `16px Arial`, all other font sizes inherited. `border:0;` for all elements. Why do browsers add 1px to button's height? So if label's height is 42px - button's height is 43px. This happens in Chrome and Firefox.

How to make the same height for buttons and labels?

[image]
[image]

**Part of code**

`<input type='checkbox' name='remember' id="remember"/><label for="remember" >Remember me</label>
<input type='submit' value='Sign in' id='signin-button' />` (in the HTML form)

Comment: Have you applied any borders ?

Comment: @ClydeLobo I wrote all borders are set to 0

Comment: Did you use *{border:0;} or something else?

Comment: If possible, can you post the HTML and CSS. Also the browser in question(i assume its a webkit based)

Comment: @ClydeLobo Take a look at the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but it probably comes down to line-heights of the fonts and how they're handled in different elements in HTML.

Try forcing a height with CSS like so:

```
#signin-button { height: 42px!important; border: none!important; overflow: hidden; }
```

I'm usually against setting exact heights for elements as a general rule, but for this case, it might just do the job and be appropriate.

Good luck.

Comment: Use `!important` only as a last resort.

Comment: just using height:42px on the button solved it for me in chrome

Comment: @Gijs problem appears because I set padding instead of fixed height. And preferred way is to stay with padding

Comment: Glad to hear it worked...but you gave the answer to someone else? And also...!important; should be used only when crucially needed as the poster above states. Try it without first.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `line-height: 17px;` , sorry if you have already tried line height.

Comment: Now, label's height is greater then button's height :D, But OK thank you